# How do I decode json Dictionary into a struct that I want and use that data to populate my Table View

Tags: swift, uikit, alamofire, jsonparser

I have a data model which is a struct and I have an API which has JSON dictionary. I need to populate my table view cells with the values in the dictionary. I have already created an array containing the key values to pass it to one of the labels in my viewcontroller. I have a text field and a label and I want the data from the API to be displayed corresponding to the array elements in my array containing keys.

This is My view controller [Edited] ;

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var DataTable: UITableView!
    
    var UserArr = ["ID", "UID", "Password", "First Name", "Last Name", "Username", "Email", "Avatar", "Gender", "Phone Number", "Social Insurance Number", "Date Of Birth", "Employment", "Address", "Zip Code", "State", "Country", "Coordinates", "CC Number", "Subscription"]
    
    var userDataFromApi = [UserData]()
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.fetchData{
            apiData in
            self.userDataFromApi = apiData
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                DataTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
        
        DataTable.dataSource = self
        DataTable.delegate = self
                       
        
    }
            
}

extension FirstViewController : UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return userDataFromApi.count
    }
   
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = DataTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
        
        let rowdata = userDataFromApi[indexPath.row]
        cell.txtLabel.text = UserArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.txtField.text = rowdata.first_name
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

My data Model

```
import Foundation

struct UserData : Codable {        
    let id : Int
    let uid : String
    let password : String
    let first_name : String
    let last_name : String
    let username : String
    let email : String
    let avatar : String
    let gender : String
    let phone_number : String
    let social_insurance_number : String
    let date_of_birth : String
    let employment : Employment
    
    
    struct Employment : Codable {
        let title : String
        let key_skill: String
    }
    
    
    let address : Address
    struct Address : Codable {
        let city : String
        let street_name : String
        let street_address : String
        let zip_code : String
        let state : String
        let country : String
        let coordinates : Coordinates
        struct Coordinates : Codable {
            let lat : Double
            let lng : Double
        }
    }
    
    
    let credit_card : Credit_card
    struct Credit_card : Codable {
        let cc_number : String
    }
    
    let subscription : Subscription?
    struct Subscription : Codable {
        let plan : String
        let status : String
        let payment_method : String
        let term : String
    }
            
}
```

Where I make API requests

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {
    static let sharedInstance = NetworkManager()
    private init() {
        
    }
    
    func fetchData(handler: @escaping (_ apiData :[UserData]) -> (Void)){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users")
        else {
            return
            
        }
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil) .response  { resp in
            switch resp.result {
            case  .success(let data) :
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([UserData].self, from: data!)
                    print("Data is : \(json)")
                    print(type(of: json))
                    handler(json)
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error) :
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
                                                
        }
    }
                
}
```

At first I tried to parse it as array but it doesn't load anything. Please feel free to suggest improvements because I am a beginner in learning Swift.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to use `userDataFromApi`. Also, you should call `reloadData()` once you got `userDataFromApi`. Unrelated but: you should name your var starting with a lower case (even IBOutlets), you could use `.responseDecodable(of:)` instead of `.response()` that will do the parsing for you.

Comment: `cell.txtLabel.text = UserArr[indexPath.row]. first_name` this will print first name.. rest you handle the way you want...

Comment: @Larme sorry to ask but how does .responseDecodable(of:) differer from .response() .I have a json dictionary on the api side and it says error because it found a dictionary instead of an array when parsing

Comment: Firstly it's a single object(UserData) not an array([UserData]). 
And reload table inside closure of NetworkManager.sharedInstance.fetchData{ } on last line after assigning. 
Lastly if still not working then double check property names of your model with json and type also

Comment: isn't `print(error)` printing something? It should and you should include that into your question as for now your error isn't even related to UITableView, but parsing...

Comment: it only prints a single field and label

Answer (score 0):

> At first I tried to parse it as array but it doesn't load anything. Please feel free to suggest improvements because I am a beginner in learning Swift.

It is because from your api you're getting dictionary and you're trying to store it in array.

you need to change you're api call function slightly.

```
func fetchData(handler: @escaping (_ apiData :UserData) -> (Void)){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users")
        else {
            return
            
        }
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil, interceptor: nil) .response  { resp in
            switch resp.result {
            case  .success(let data) :
                do {
                    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: data!)
                    print("Data is : \(json)")
                    print(type(of: json))
                    handler(json)
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            case .failure(let error) :
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.fetchData{
    apiData in
    print("api data - ",apiData)
    // you can save your data in array accordingly
}
```